# How to log HTTP and HTTPS traffic for mobile devices like Android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, logging, proxy, forward

I have the following setup:

Mobile Clients (Android and iOS) are communicating with 3 servers directly using HTTPS rest requests with json body.

I want to host a server in the middle and send all requests when the application is used in one of the non-PROD environments and log every request and response. In real time the developers or QAs to open a web page and see in real time every activity the application is doing.

Also: Apply some filters, for example only requests to a specific address, or everything but specific address. Apply delays and change the request/response body or status code - like in Fiddler.

In order to achieve this today I have to host Fiddler or Charles proxy and setup the computer as proxy server to every device.

What can you advise me to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can host a Fiddler proxy on your server. Also in the Fiddler settings, don't forget to mark the 'Decrypt HTTPS' setting if you want to see the HTTPS traffic.

Fiddler will give you a certificate which you will need to install on mobile devices so that Fiddler can decrypt HTTPS connections.

Set your proxy in the Wifi settings.

Make sure that your app uses the proxy settings which are set in the Wifi Settings. I have seen some apps which ignore the proxy settings.

Answer (score 1):

you can setup a wifi proxy server and ask all the the devices to connect through that wifi proxy server...Now you can monitor traffic on that proxy server...

On Linux server you can use *squid* to setup wifi proxy -http://computernetworkingnotes.com/network-administrations/squid-server.html

To setup wifi proxy on android device go to Go to *Settings/Wi-Fi-> "Show advanced options"-> "Proxy settings" and choose "manual"*