# react-native : Get internal api call data from url of the WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-webview

I have a webview with a url (for example a payment processing page). When the url is loaded, certain api calls are done and i want to know how to get data from the internal api calls of that particular url.

It is not something like communication between webpage and react native code. ( `window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage` or `onMessage` )
 I need internal api call response data from the webpage.

Comment: If you have access to that website code, you can always set a cookie and check that in react native

Comment: @Kaushik Can you elaborate??

Comment: @FortuneCookie Did you find any solution? I am facing same issue. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you put the code which you are using and what API you are trying to get. This will help understand better and give a solution

Comment: What the proposal of getting this data, it's for debug? or for your example you need to know the result of payment processing page?

Comment: So just so I get this right, you're trying to man in the middle some third party call that's occuring inside the WebView page so you can change your app based on the random internal data calls response?

Answer (score 2):

## Solution 1:

you can inject js into webview to get api detail

```
var open = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
    this.addEventListener("load", function() {
        var message = {"status" : this.status, "responseURL" : this.responseURL}
        webkit.messageHandlers.handler.postMessage(message);
    });
    open.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

## Solution 2:

right now, there is no way to intercept webview internal API calls.

you can add support for this in webview

#### Android

In android you have to use
`WebViewClient.shouldInterceptRequest()`

you can add bridging method [REF](https://github.com/1rahul1/react-native-webview/blob/5f33934f25f4bfb35c1dc45ab83efd2b1567d7bb/android/src/main/java/com/reactnativecommunity/webview/RNCWebViewManager.java#L806)

Comment: I tried this and it works great on iOS but it isn't working on Android. For some reason, the API calls made by the webpage that I'm loading aren't showing up on Android (but other api calls are showing). I figure it has something to do with the `shouldInterceptRequest` but not sure. I replaced my `react-native-webview` library with the fork you linked, and it didn't solve this issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can inspect/log the network requests by setting up a (WiFi) proxy:

- [Step-by-step instructions for Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-capture-android-traffic-with-fiddler)
- [Another how-to for Proxyman](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-debug-network-requests-in-ios-android-apps-b74ce50cd379)
- [Related StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34227879/117030)